# Quantlib: Bond with both callable and puttable options

Tags: quantlib

I am trying to use quantlib to price a bond with both callable and puttable options. I have seen examples for pricing callable bonds using `ql.CallabilitySchedule()`. I would like to ask how to include dates and strike prices for both put and call options in `ql.CallabilitySchedule()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, I haven't tried this myself but if you look at [example](https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruments/bonds.html#callable-bond), where I am reposting below the relevant part:

```
putCallSchedule.append(
    ql.Callability(callability_price, ql.Callability.Call, ql.Date(15,6,2021))
)
```

The 2nd argument to the `ql.Callability` is the `Type` which can be either `Call` or `Put`. Therefore, try adding your `Put` days using `ql.Callability.Put` instead of `ql.Callability.Call`.